# why the output of T5 model contains <extra_id_0> ,.... when the input is not mask

Tags: huggingface-transformers, summarization, seq2seq

I fintuned  mT5 with new dataset for summarization task.
In the inference phase, mT5 generate outputs contains <extra_id_1>, ... when the input is not mask.

I use the blow code to encode the input:

`tokenized_inputs = self.tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
[line],
max_length=self.max_len,

```
          padding="max_length",
          return_tensors="pt"
        ).to(self.args.device)`
```

and use the code below for generating output:

```
`Summary_input_ids= model. generate(
        input_ids=input_ids,
        attention_mask=input_mask,
        do_sample=True,                                                         
        temperature=0.8,                                                         
        top_k=45,                                                               
        top_p=0.9,                                                              
        max_length=_max_length,                                                 
        min_length=_min_length,                                                           
        num_beams=_num_beams,                                                   
        repetition_penalty=2.5,
        no_repeat_ngram_size = _no_repeat_ngram_size,
        length_penalty=2.5,
        early_stopping=False,                                                   
        use_cache=True,
        num_return_sequences=1)
   Summary = tokenizer.batch_decode(Summary_input_ids,
                                     skip_special_tokens=True,clean_up_tokenization_spaces=False) `
```

I want to generate summary for each input  because the model has been fine-tuned in supervised manner.